# update aggregate doesn't modify all the documents

Tags: mongodb

Sample data:

```
{
  _id: ,
  instances: [
    {
     instance_id: ObjectId()
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to convert to ObjectId to String format in the instances array.

I came up with the below query

```
db.test.update(  
  {'_id': {'$in': ['1054605|2347', '1053095|2404']}},
  [ 
    {
    $set: {
      i: {
        $map: {
          input: "$instances",
          as: "instance",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$instance",
              {
                instance_id: {
                  $cond: {
                    if: {
                     $eq:[ { $type: "$$instance.instance_id"} , "objectId"]
                  },
                  
                  then: {
                      $convert:{ 
                          input: "$$instance.instance_id", 
                          to: "string"
                     }
                 },
                    else: "$$instance.instance_id"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ])
```

But the above query works for only one document. But it doesn't work on multiple documents, it simply says updated 0 documents.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue here is the Model.update() function

`Update()` function updates one object but that behaviour can be overridden by adding the `multi: true` to the update function as mentioned in the documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/).

Having said that, you can also use a more "cleaner" approach to the situation by using the `updateMany()` instead of `update()` with `multi: true`.

`updateMany()` is same as `update()`, except MongoDB will update all documents that match filter regardless of the value of the multi option.

This would offer a cleaner and more readable piece of code. Documentation to `updateMany()` can be found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/).

Comment: Kindly give an upvote to Tom's answer as I could approve only one.

Comment: Thanks for that @Gibbs but don't worry i'll be fine :).

Answer (score 3):

You are using the [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) method:

> By default, the db.collection.update() method updates a single document. Include the option multi: true to update all documents that match the query criteria.

All you have to do is add the `multi: true` flag to the update options, like so:

```
db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>,
   {
     multi: true,
   }
)
```